# ssl file permission on postgresql 14 is not right

Tags: postgresql, ssl

After enabling ssl on postgresql 14, there is error when starting the Postgres server:

```
2022-05-13 00:09:39.791 CST [938050] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/postgresql/14/main/server.key" has group or world access
2022-05-13 00:23:09.163 CST [938097] DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.
```

What I did is to following the hint above and `chmod 640 server.key`. Here is the current permission output after `chmod` (seems only remove r for group)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      2727 May 13 00:08 server.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root     root      3323 May 13 00:08 server.csr
-rw-r----- 1 root     root      1704 May 13 00:08 server.key
```

But restarting Postgres server still has error:

```
2022-05-13 00:38:09.331 CST [938235] FATAL:  could not load private key file "/etc/postgresql/14/main/server.key": Permission denied
    2022-05-13 00:38:09.331 CST [938235] LOG:  database system is shut down
    pg_ctl: could not start server
```

What is missing here with the ssl file permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the ownership of all files to the PostgreSQL user:

```sh
chown postgres server.crt server.key server.csr
```

Then remove the read permissions for the group from the private key file:

```sh
chmod g-r server.key
```